# mod_wsgi windows binary required for apache 2.2 and python 3.5

Tags: mod-wsgi

I need   the   mod_wsgi   whl  file for  win 64 bit-Apache webserver 2.2 +Python 3.5

I searched   for it     but could not get it. I have  the  one for apache version 2.4

Where   do I get it?

when I   try pip install mod-wsgi I get error

```
(r_web) C:\Users\Administrator\r_web\RosterWeb>pip install mod-wsgi

Collecting mod-wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.5.11.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-xybcspx9\mod-wsgi\s
etup.py", line 150, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
    RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not execu
table. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this pack
age and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

Comment: Question also asked on mod_wsgi mailing list where answer was provided. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/modwsgi/xp1ZPBp3zro/xfbxKImKEwAJ